# When creating an API Notebook with a hyphen separated resource name "/songs-list" , it gives an error

Tags: exchange-server, mulesoft, mule4, raml-1.0, anypoint-platform

When creating an API Notebook with a hyphen seperated resource name "/songs-list" on RAML 1.0 , API Platform 2.0, it gives the below error :
[APINotebook Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRo2K.png)

`API.createClient('client', '9c2861a1-b**b-401e-****-1ec*****b20c', 'testhyphen', '1.0.2');`

$0=Client has been successfully created

`client.songs-list.post[{"msg":"succ"}];`

```
$1=ReferenceError: list is not defined
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (eval at value (https://cdn.anypoint.mulesoft.com/artifacts/exchange-ui/main.efc15523965187f6c807.js:1:998504)), <anonymous>:1:14)
at Object.eval (eval at value (https://cdn.anypoint.mulesoft.com/artifacts/exchange-ui/main.efc15523965187f6c807.js:1:998504), <anonymous>:3:8)
at e.value (https://cdn.anypoint.mulesoft.com/artifacts/exchange-ui/main.efc15523965187f6c807.js:1:998611)
at https://cdn.anypoint.mulesoft.com/artifacts/exchange-ui/main.efc15523965187f6c807.js:1:2212756
at h.run (https://cdn.anypoint.mulesoft.com/artifacts/exchange-ui/main.efc15523965187f6c807.js:1:282445)
at p (https://cdn.anypoint.mulesoft.com/artifacts/exchange-ui/main.efc15523965187f6c807.js:1:281939)
at nrWrapper (https://anypoint.mulesoft.com/exchange/9c2861a1-b**b-401e-****-1ec*****b20c/testhyphen/minor/1.0/:1:24554)
```

RAML of the above asset is as below with reource name "/songs-list":

```
     #%RAML 1.0
     title: testhyphen
     /songs-list:
        post:
          body:
            application/json:
          responses:
            200:
              body:
                application/json:
                  example: {"messgae": "Success"}
```

If the resource name does not contain "-" (hyphen), eg when resource is - "/songs", then the API notebook runs as expected.
[API Notebook success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWnaz.png)

`API.createClient('client', '9c2861a1-b**b-401e-****-1ec*****b20c', 'testset', '1.0.1');`

`$0=Client has been successfully created`

`client.songs.post[{"msg":"succ"}];`

`Code snippet executed with no results`

Comment: Looks like your hyphen is interpreted as a `minus` sign when you execute `.post`.

Comment: @smwhr Yes, is there any way to represent a hyphen to avoid this misinterpretation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this format to run it successfully:

```
clients['songs-list'].post[{"msg":"succ"}];
```

Without that format, it sees the hyphen as a subtraction operator. Since APINotebook runs on JavaScript, and supports any JavaScript syntax, you can look up how to do things in JavaScript and they should work with APINotebook.